# Can't install Android SDK - Unrecognizable characters on setup wizard

Tags: windows, windows-10, android, android-studio

I'm trying to install it, as administrator, but I can't read anything on the setup, as the image:

[image: I'm trying to install it, as administrator, but I cant read anything on the setup, as the image HERE]

Comment: What is the language on your system?

Comment: My Windows 10 is set to English (United States) as the display language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, it was something wrong with the default font in my system. Changed to Verdana with the .reg below, restarted the system and the problem was gone. Make sure you have Verdana installed.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
"Segoe UI Symbol (TrueType)"=""
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
"Segoe UI"="Verdana"
```